# Razor View Syntax doesn't recognize the "@" in an HTML attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-migration

I am migrating a project from MVC 2 to MVC3 and the razor view engine.

In MVC 2, I would have the following html:

```
<div id="del_<%= Model.ActivityID.ToString() %>"></div>
```

When using razor, I tried the following, which renders the literal text "del_@Model.ActivityID.ToString()" when I want del_1.

```
<div id="del_@Model.ActivityID.ToString()"></div>
```

To get around the issue, I used:

```
<div id="@Model.ActivityID.ToString()_del"></div>
```

Is there away to make razor work with this syntax?

```
<div id="del_@Model.ActivityID.ToString()"></div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to use the `@()` around your particular model value like so:

```
<div id="del_@(Model.ActivityID.ToString())"></div>
```

The reason for this is because the `del_@Model.ActivityID` looks like an email address to the parser and by default the parser tries to ignore email addresses so you don't have to do something silly like `john@@doe.com` as emails are common enough that it would be annoying to do every time. So the people working on the razor parser just figured: "if it looks like an email, ignore it". So that's why you're having this particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="del_@(Model.ActivityID.ToString())"></div>
```

In case you didn't see the trick: use `@(   )`