# Razor syntax isn't recognizing '@' after an underscore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to do the following:

```
@foreach(var p in @Model.line_products){
<img class="small_img_@Model.line_products[i].short_name" src="/Content/images/@Model.line_products[i].image_name" />
}
```

Which isn't working, it renders the text just the way it is, not recognizing the '@'. I found this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377317/razor-view-syntax-doesnt-recognize-the-in-an-html-attribute) in Stackoverflow, which suggests adding parenthesis in the following way:

```
@foreach(var p in @Model.line_products){
<img class="small_img_(@Model.line_products[i].short_name)" src="/Content/images/@Model.line_products[i].image_name" />
}
```

Using this workaround, I get that my id is rendered as small_img_(**MODEL ATTRIBUTE**). Isn't there a workaround which doesn't require adding specific characters? (such as the parenthesis).

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you sure you want to be using an index in a foreach loop? Should your markup be `small_img_@(p.short_name)` instead?

Comment: Context please? Which text rendered the way it is? What comes before this markup?

Comment: I am using the index for html purposes, and so I forgot to use the p variable declared in the foreach. When the 'i' variable reaches certain values I open/close <tr> tags. You were right! It was as simple as placing the '@' outside. Silly mistake, thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have more errors than a simple undercore problem here. You cannot use @Model inside your if. You are already in a @ block. Simply use `@foreach(var p in Model.line_products)`.

Plus, the way you wrote the parenthesis, they will get rendered. What you want is

```
small_img_@(Model.line_products[i].short_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the parenthesis after the `@` instead of before:

```
class="small_img_@(Model.line_products[i].short_name)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes put a couple of Guids in the id of an element and an underscore separator doesn't work.

There are two ways around this. First use the entity code `&#95;` instead and secondly just use a hyphen.

```
 <input id="chk_@classLeader.ClassLeader&#95;@ing.Ingredient.Guid" type="checkbox" class="chk_Done form-check">

 <input id="chk-@classLeader.ClassLeader-@ing.Ingredient.Guid" type="checkbox" class="chk_Done form-check">
```

This is because I want to grab out the Guid's when the check box is clicked with some JQuery like this:

```
$(".chk_Done").click(function () {

    var obj =[];

    const itemId = ($(this).attr("id"));
    const myArray = itemId.split("_");
    var ClassLeaderGuid = myArray[1], IngredientGuid = myArray[2];
```